# Twig + wordpress - how to get filemtime for style.css

Tags: css

I'm using twig + timber in my wordpress theme. I have style.css file included in this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.theme.uri }}/dist/css/style.min.css" />
```

I want to add `?ver=xxxx` to prevent file caching. My question is how to implement filemtime function? I want to make it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.theme.uri }}/dist/css/style.min.css?ver=1202120210" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use Twig's [`date`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) filter to append the current Unix timestamp via `{{ 'now'|date('U') }}` or `{{ date().format('U') }}`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.theme.uri }}/dist/css/style.min.css?ver={{ 'now'|date('U') }}" />
```